# Wrap_Layout does not wrap layout, unless in a RelativeLayout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

Inside this

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/backgroundColor"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="12dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clipChildren="false"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:orientation="vertical">
```

I have this

```
<RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/banner_rl"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="330:128"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.9">

                    <ImageView ... />

                    <TextView ... />
                </RelativeLayout>
            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
```

Unless I insert that outermost RelativeLayout, the ConstraintLayout would not wrap the Image. it would be 0dp instead of the content's.
Why is that? Why does the CL need to be wrapped by a RL to identify it's contents?

Comment: what's the point of using constraint layout, relative layout AND linear layout ? usually the point of using constraint layout is to remove the need for all of these nested layout structures, consider getting rid of your relative and linear layouts. removing all of these will already simplify life to the point where you won't have these unnecessary issues

Comment: The first relative is for the wrap_content, the second is for a view overlap.